# How do I access the API documentation from the command line on Linux?

Tags: rust

Is there a command to access rust-lang api documentation from the linux command line?

I'm after something similar to this example for golang documentation:

`godoc strings Contains`

which gives the output:

> PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION
>
> package strings
>       import "strings"
>
> FUNCTIONS
>
> func Contains(s, substr string) bool
>       Contains returns true if substr is within s.

I know there is a `rustdoc` command, but it only generates documentation, it doesn't display it.

Comment: I think you'll need to pipe the output of `rustdoc` into an HTML parser, and then grep that for the function. You could probably set up a simple shell script to do this, or even a shell alias. Have a look at http://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/ (should be available on most Unices), in particular `hxextract`.

Comment: I'm not much of sysadmin guy, maybe if you can elaborate because when I type `rustdoc vec::each`, I get error. Piping the output of error won't do much good.

Comment: I don't think you can do that yet. See https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/2207 . It's probably not too far off though, they're moving very quickly at the moment!

Comment: I will leave this question open then, in future if any answers arrive, Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

We don't have a tool like this yet, but would like one. https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/650 is tracking this issue.

( Formerly tracked as https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6160 )

Answer (score 1):

The only solution so far would be to use command line browser like lynx and go to  http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html.

Or as Intermernet noted you could pipe HTML docs into grep function. If I'm not mistaken, the nightlies should come with complied docs, if you require API docs.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small shell function to generate and open the docs within a project in the terminal using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) and [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/):

```
cli-rustdoc () {
    cargo doc -p "$1"; pandoc "target/doc/$1/index.html" | lynx -stdin
}
```

Usage example: `$ cli-rustdoc rand`

Not perfect, but it does the trick for the most part.